# How to remove click effect in HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

Hello developer/programmer,

good afternoon, I am developing a website using `PHP`, `JavaScript`, `HTML` and `CSS`. I have a problem. when I run website in mobile and when click on any item, button then it show effect, but I don't want that effect.

How to remove button click effect /  button on click effect.

- *in desktop button click effect not show*

[button click effect in mobile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UH3BDW1rzlotTFXhjys0NLNyNL3LMAIB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "click" effect seems to be a tap highlight color.

Adding the following css to your `html` tag should do the trick:

```
html {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

It set the tap highlight color to transparent.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries in your css file to avoid what you want to avoid in touch devices. you can do it in two way:

```
/* for devices that can hover, like laptop */
@media (hover: hover) {
  .your-button-class {
     styles...
  }
}

/* for devices that can not hover, like phones*/
@media (hover: none) {
  .your-button-class {
     styles...
  }
}
```